# Is paying extra for "Controlled Impedance" boards necessary?

Tags: pcb, impedance, transmission-line

I'm doing a bit of RF PCB design, and one of the things that caught my eye is the "Controlled Impedance" option. Checking more boxes always costs more, so I want to know if this is worth the extra money to ensure functionality on arrival. For the RF portion, I'm using 50 ohm microstrip-line on a 4 layer board. (Top layer [1] is signal, top inner layer [2] is a ground plane)

Most board vendors have made their laminate stack-up contents and thicknesses available on their website, and I have been able to calculate the width of the transmission line to my satisfaction using their numbers.

- What is the benefit of using
  "controlled impedance" or "controlled
  dielectric"?
- At small distances (about 1/10 wavelength), would the impedance bump matter? (I get about 2 ohms difference in Zo from changing the dielectric constant by +-0.4)
- Is this something that should be done for production boards but isn't necessary for one-off prototypes?
- Have you ever used this feature?

Comment: Your title is an "it depends" question.

Comment: I'll be sure to ask only yes/no questions in the future.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you specify controlled impedance/controlled dielectric, they will test your board to ensure that the traces are at the specified impedance.  In your fabrication notes on your PCB printout, specify the nets and their targeted impedance (with tolerance, e.g., 50 ohms +/- 2 ohms).

They will either test a small test strip that is manufactured on the same panel as your boards; or they will test all nets as needed.  This will help catch boards that do not meet spec, before they end up being stuffed with components.

BTW, the "weave" of the board may affect the actual impedance of any particular trace, even when the traces are built to spec (see [PCB Dielectric Material Selection and Fiber Weave Effect on High-Speed Channel Routing - Altera Application Note](http://www.altera.com/literature/an/an528.pdf)).

Your board fabrication note should specify what the target impedance is, and on which traces those impedance values apply to.   (Example: Trace width of 8 mils shall be at 50 ohms +/- 10%.)  The fabricator may adjust your trace width slightly to meet the target impedance.

Comment: The weave of the board can affect the impedance of a trace?  That makes me cringe.

Comment: @Kevin -- it's because FR-x materials are composites consisting of glass fibers (the F) and resin (the R). If you want consistent performance use a substrate that is more homogenous like a ceramic-filled resin (ex. Rogers).

Answer (score 6):

For a controlled dielectric board, they probably take more care in doing the stackup, as well as using better materials. I'm currently using controlled impedance boards, but have skipped it in the past at 1.8 GHz for Cell phones.

For short runs, you likely won't see much of an issue for an impedance bump. If you're going to do it in production, then you should prototype with it as well.

If you're doing small boards and short traces, then you probably can skip the controlled impedance and live with what you get. You may see some slightly higher trace insertion losses with an uncontrolled board, but that might not matter.

Comment: Dave - Thanks for the voice of experience! However, "they probably take more care" isn't very authoritative or specific. Can you point to some evidence of this?

Comment: Also, the tagline is unnecessary - Your signature is already at the bottom right, with an avatar, information on your badges/rep, and a link to your profile.

Comment: Here's an interesting link I came across http://www.freelists.org/post/si-list/Fr-4-Er-variation that should help with this.